# How to reset Form with node.js with button using express

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I have a simple form and need to have a reset button to reset the value back to the original state.
I have tried an href to reload the page and for some reason, it adds onto it. example `reset   I get /home/home/view back. I have a router and controller set up. I believe I can redirect it back to my page. I have no idea how to do this with Node using the router and the controller with an onClick.

My starting page :

```
 <form action="/home/views" method="POST" > <!-- a form passes the information to the server-->

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2 pt-2 pl-4">
            <lable for="nameInput">Enter name:</lable>
            <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="nameInput" value="<%=name%>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <% if( errors.length > 0 ) {%> 
                    <% for(let ctr = 0; ctr < errors.length; ctr++) {%> 
                        <%if( errors[ctr].param == "nameInput" ) {%>
                        <li class="errorText"><%=errors[ctr].msg %></li>
                        <% } %> 
                        <% } %> 
                <% } %>  
            </div>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col pt-2 pl-4 pr-0">
            <lable for="timesInput">How many times to display?</lable>
            <input type="text" id="timesInput" name="timesInput" value="<%=times%>">  
            </div>
            <div class="col-9"> 
                 <% if( errors.length > 0 ) {%> 

                <% for(let ctr = 0; ctr < errors.length; ctr++) {%> 
                    <%if( errors[ctr].param == "timesInput" ) {%>
                    <li  class="errorText"><%=errors[ctr].msg %></li>
                    <% } %> 
                    <% } %> 
            <% } %>    
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        &nbsp;
       
        <input type="submit" value="Display Hello!"/>
        &nbsp;
        <a href = "/home/views  class="btn btn-primary" role="button" name="resetForm"> Reset</a>
        <!-- onClick="window.location.reload();" -->
    </form>
    <% if(errors.length > 0) {%> 

        <% }else {%> 

    <%if(name.length > 0 ){ %>
    <div>
        <% for(let ctr=0; ctr <times; ctr++) {%>
            <h1>
               
                <%= ctr + 1%>.<%if(ctr % 2==1){ %>
                        <%=name%>!
                            <%}else{%>
                                <%=name%>
                                    <%}%>
                                    
            </h1>
            <% } %>
    </div>
    <% } %> 
    <% } %>
```

My Router:

```
function router() {

    const {getViews,postViews } = homeController();
   
    homeRouter.route("/views").get(getViews);

    homeRouter.post(
        "/views", 
      
        check("nameInput").not().isEmpty()
                .withMessage("You must enter a name"),

                check("timesInput").not().isEmpty()
                .withMessage("You must enter a number"),

                check("timesInput")
                .isNumeric()
                .withMessage("You must enter a number"),

        postViews;
```

My Controller :

```
function homeController() {
  
    let errors = {};
    function getViews(req, res) {
        res.render('home/views',{
            name:"",
            times:0,
            errors
        });
    }
    function postViews(req, res){
        const valErrors = validationResult(req);
  
        errors = valErrors.array();

        res.render('home/views',{
            name: req.body.nameInput,
            times: req.body.timesInput,
            errors
            
    
        })
    }


    return {
        getViews,
        postViews

    }

}

module.exports = HomeController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page won't help you out.

When refreshing, the same form will be re-sent to the backed server and you will get the same results back, which are the content of the parsed `home/views` view.

You form submission flow is erroneous as you should not be re-rendering (*redirecting* to) the same view / endpoint toward which you are *POST*ing your form otherwise you will end-up in endless back and forth loop as is the case. That being said, you should render to another success / failure view based on your business logic:

```
function postViews(req, res){
    const valErrors = validationResult(req);  
    errors = valErrors.array();
    if (!errors.length) {
        // redirect to success view on form validation success
        res.render('views/home/success',{
            name: req.body.nameInput,
            times: req.body.timesInput
        })
    } else {
        // redirect to same view with `errors` to be displayed
        res.render('home/views',{
            name: req.body.nameInput,
            times: req.body.timesInput,
            errors
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  How would I add the reset button to clear the form? I want to make a  larger form with the ability to clear the form with a button if the user chooses to.